# Do movement cards need to be played continuously?

Tags: quest-for-el-dorado

In Quest for El Dorado can movement from cards be interspersed?

For example with a 3 machete and 1 sailor could I move forest-forest-sailor-forest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not played this game but reading the rules [here](https://cdn.1j1ju.com/medias/fc/6a/fa-the-quest-for-el-dorado-rulebook.pdf) it seems clear you can not.  The rules say (emphasis mine).

> If you have “leftover” power, you may use it to continue moving to **the
> next space**. The same 2 requirements apply, but you first subtract the
> power you already spent from the played card’s power value. You can
> stop moving at any time. In that case, you lose any unspent power
> immediately.

If you have left over power on a card it can only be used for **the next space**.  if it is not then then the power is lost.   As soon as the sailor card is played to move then any power left on the card with machete symbol are lost.

I did not see any indication in the rules that would allow you to use unspent power on a card after a new card for movement has been played.